# Will Collections.synchronizedMap be thread safe if synchronized while iteration?

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm trying to fix a bug related to `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating a `Collections.synchronizedMap`.

As asked by the Javadoc, the iteration process has been synchronized on the map.

I checked the iteration process, there is no obvious modification on the size of the map(the method calling trace is very long which I will double check).

Other than the modification during the iteration process, is there any other possibility that may cause this exception?

Since the iteration is already synchronized, from my understanding, other thread won't be able to do modifications like `add()` or `remove()`, is this right?

I'm really new to these stuff. Any help will be really appreciated.

**Updating**

Thanks so much for everybody's help especially the detailed explanations from  @Marco13. I did a small code to test and verify this problem and the code is attached here:

```
public class TestCME {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestMap tm = new TestMap();
        for(int i = 0;i < 50;i++){
            tm.addCity(i,new City(i * 10));
        }
        RunnableA rA = new RunnableA(tm);
        new Thread(rA).start();
        RunnableB rB = new RunnableB(tm);
        new Thread(rB).start();
    }
}
class TestMap{
    Map<Integer,City> cityMap;

    public TestMap(){
        cityMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer,City>());
    }

    public Set<Integer> getAllKeys(){
        return cityMap.keySet();
    }

    public City getCity(int id){
        return cityMap.get(id);
    }

    public void addCity(int id,City city){
        cityMap.put(id,city);
    }

    public void removeCity(int id){
        cityMap.remove(id);
    }
}
class City{
    int area;
    public City(int area){
        this.area = area;
    }
}
class RunnableA implements Runnable{
    TestMap tm;
    public RunnableA(TestMap tm){
        this.tm = tm;
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread A is starting to run......");

        if(tm != null && tm.cityMap != null && tm.cityMap.size() > 0){

            synchronized (tm.cityMap){
                Set<Integer> idSet = tm.getAllKeys();
                Iterator<Integer> itr = idSet.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println("Entering while loop.....");
                    Integer id = itr.next();
                    System.out.println(tm.getCity(id).area);
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            /*Set<Integer> idSet = tm.getAllKeys();
            Iterator<Integer> itr = idSet.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println("Entering while loop.....");
                Integer id = itr.next();
                System.out.println(tm.getCity(id).area);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }*/

        }
    }
}
class RunnableB implements Runnable{
    TestMap tm;
    public RunnableB(TestMap tm){
        this.tm = tm;
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread B is starting to run......");
        System.out.println("Trying to add elements to map....");
        tm.addCity(50,new City(500));
        System.out.println("Trying to remove elements from map....");
        tm.removeCity(1);
    }
}
```

I was trying to recover my bug so the code is a little lengthy and I'm sorry for that. In thread A, I am doing the iteration on the map while in thread B I'm trying to add to and remove elements from map. With the correct synchronization on the map(as @Marco13 advised), I won't see ConcurrentModificationException, if without the synchronization or synchronized on TestMap object, the exception shows up. I guess I understand this problem now. Any double confirmation or suggestion on this is very welcome. Thanks again very much.

Comment: I suggest you post a self-contained, reproducible example and the relevant stack trace, otherwise it will be difficult to help you and your question might get closed.

Comment: If you hold the lock, there are only two ways, how the map still can get modified, 1. by the thread which owns the lock, 2. through a reference to the original map that has been wrapped by `Collections.synchronizedMap`. In order to avoid the second option, you should not keep any reference to the wrapped map. Regarding the first one, only a careful code analysis will help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments. I added a sample code which throws the exception. I'm doing the code analysis now. For the second reason, could you give me more details or docs? I'm not very clear about the wrapped map. Thank you very much.

Comment: Help us by posting the stack trace of the `ConcurrentModificationException` you get.

Comment: @AliceTan, where's the sample code?

Comment: @llogiq Sorry I was trying to edit my question this morning but rushed to go outside. I have updated my question with some code. Thanks very much for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some general statements, based on the code that had been added (and removed again in the meantime, for whatever reason).

> EDIT Also see the update at the bottom of the answer

You should be aware of *what* you are actually synchronizing on. When you are creating a map with

```
Map<Key, Value> synchronizedMap = 
    Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
```

then the synchronization will take place on the `synchronizedMap`. This means that the following is thread-safe:

```
void executedInFirstThread() 
{
    synchronizedMap.put(someKey, someValue);
}
void executedInSecondThread() 
{
    synchronizedMap.remove(someOtherKey);
}
```

Although both methods may be exectued at the same time by different threads, it is thread safe: When the first thread executes the `put` method, then the second thread will have to *wait* before executing the `remove` method. The `put` and the `remove` method will *never* be executed at the same time. This is what the synchronization is for.

---

However, the meaning of a `ConcurrentModificationException` is broader. Regarding the particular case, and a bit simplified: The `ConcurrentModificationException` indicates that the map was modified **while** an iteration over the map was in progress.

Therefore, one has to synchronize *the whole iteration*, and not only single methods:

```
void executedInFirstThread() 
{
    synchronized (synchronizedMap)
    {
        for (Key key : synchronizedMap.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(synchronizedMap.get(key));
        }
    }
}
void executedInSecondThread() 
{
    synchronizedMap.put(someKey, someValue);
}
```

Without the `synchronized` block, the first thread could *partially* iterate over the map, and then, in the middle of the iteration, the second thread could call `put` on the map (thus, performing a *concurrent modification*). When the first thread then wanted to continue with the iteration, a `ConcurrentModificationException` would be thrown.

With the `synchronized` block, this can not happen: When the first thread enters this `synchronized` block, then the second thread will have to wait before it may call `put`. (It will have to wait until the first thread leaves the `synchronized` block. Afterwards, it can safely do the modification).

---

However, note that this whole concept always refers to **an object that is synchronized on**.

In your case, you had a class similar to the following:

```
class TestMap
{
    Map<Key, Value> synchronizedMap = 
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Key, Value>());

    public Set<Key> getAllKeys()
    {
        return synchronizedMap.keySet();
    }
}
```

Then, you used it like this:

```
    TestMap testMap = new TestMap();
    synchronized(testMap)
    {
        Set<Key> keys = testMap.getAllKeys();
        for (Key key : keys)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, you are synchronizing on the `testMap` object, and **not** on the `sychronizedMap` object that it contains. Thus, there is no synchronization taking place for the iteration. One thread could do the iteration (synchronized on the `testMap` object). At the same time, a different thread could (concurrently) modify the `synchronizedMap`, which would lead to a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

The solution depends on the overall structure. One possible solution would be to expose the `synchronizedMap`...

```
class TestMap
{
    Map<Key, Value> synchronizedMap = 
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Key, Value>());

    ...

    public Object getSynchronizationMonitor()
    {
        return synchronizedMap;
    }
}
```

and use it for the synchronization of the iteration...

```
TestMap testMap = new TestMap();
synchronized(testMap.getSynchronizationMonitor())
{
    ...
}
```

... but this is **not a general recommendation**, but **only intended to convey the idea**: You have to know what object you have to synchronize on. For the real application, there are most likely more elegant solutions.

> Update:

Another remark, now that the "real" code has been added to the question again: You could also consider a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). It is *explicitly designed* to be used concurrently, and does all the necessary synchronization internally - particularly, it uses some tricks internally to avoid "large" synchronization blocks. In the code that is currently shown in the question, the map will be "locked" while iterating over it, and no other thread will be able to do any modification to the map, which may negatively impact the overall performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed help. I guess I finally understand this now. Some code was added by me. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That's also what I'm concerned about.